# jQuery datatables - display row count on table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable on my view and i'm using pagination to display 10, 20, 50 or 100 rows on a single page. I would like to display somewhere on the table row count. So if i have say 400 rows displayed by 10 on each page message would be Showing 1 - 10 of 400 rows. I can't seem to find how to do it.

Solution:

(This event fires up when data is loaded into table, i can get data length and display it where ever i want)

```
table = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable({
            fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings, json) {
                console.log('Total row count on load - ', table.fnGetData().length);
            },
```

Comment: you want to show the message ` Showing 1 - 10 of 400 rows` in some other place in page , right ?

Comment: Yea, i had a problem since data comes with a little delay. I managed to find event that fires up when table is filled with data. it's table = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable({
                //"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings, json) {
                //    //console.log('Total row count on load - ', table.fnGetData().length);
                //},

Comment: it would help someone in future if post it as answer (as new post or as solution in your question itself) @azza idz

Answer (score 9):

You need to set [`info`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/info) to `true`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        'info': true
    } );
} );
```

Also if you have defined [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option, make sure there is character `i` present in the string, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        'dom': 'lfrtip',
        'info': true
    } );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to take a look at [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html).
Use the option `paginationType: 'full_numbers'`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#example").DataTable({
    "dom": '<lfip><t><ip>',
    "info": true
  });
});
```

Comment: Please, add more details, to your answer, further explaining your code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

(This event fires up when data is loaded into table, i can get data length and display it where ever i want)

```
table = $('#MyDataTable').dataTable({
            fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings, json) {
                console.log('Total row count on load - ', table.fnGetData().length);
            },
```

Comment: Why down vote it if i may know? This will give correct row number.